# Pygame What happens if I don't use self before a variable in a class?

Tags: class, pygame, definition

I read about this pixels variable in a class online and it doesn't use self before it. Do I need to use self? Does it make it a variable that is global among all the functions in a class? Does self make it only available in that function? Thanks in advance.

Oh and here is the code:

```
def moveRight(self, pixels):
    self.rect.x += pixels
```

See? The pixels variable does not use self before it.

Comment: `self` is a reference to an instance of the class it is defined. `pixels` is just a parameter. It may or may not be an object of another class.

Answer (score 1):

`rect` is a member of a class presumably, and following the Python idea that "explicit is better than implicit", `rect` is accessed using `self` so it's clear that it's a member of the class.

`pixels` however is just a parameter of the function. `self.pixels` would imply that the class `moveRight` it's in has a `pixels` member, which doesn't seem to be the case since `pixels` is being passed in.

`self` is a reference to the object you're currently "inside". `self.someVariable` only makes sense if `someVariable` is a member of the class.